# What is the maximum theoretical limit on how much a HDD can store

Tags: quantum-mechanics, information

I was wounding what was the maximum theoretical limit on how much a HDD(with 5 platters and a 3.5 inch size drive) can store because they have 6[TB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terabyte) (not to be confuse with [TiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tebibyte))  Because most people do.  There is a limit on how close they can put the hard to the platter due to Quantum tunnelling.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2281/maximum-theoretical-data-density?rq=1 due to I don't understand it or it doesn't.

Comment: Just "I don't understand it" isn't really enough to justify asking a new question. It's kind of expected around here that if you don't understand an answer, you go out and look up what you need to know to understand it. If you can identify a specific concept in that other question's answers that is confusing you, or at least narrow down this question by specifying a level such that the other question's answers don't apply, then this can probably be reopened (i.e. unmarked as a duplicate).

Comment: @DavidZ  There is a limit on how much they can put into the platter, but the head in order to read from the it, must be closer....  Which that question/answer doesn't take into account.  If you are not sure what I am taking about since you are not good with IT here is a short video....  And you should understand after watching it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Harddrive-engineerguy.ogv from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive